# `::timestamptz at time zone <zone1> at time zone <zone2>` returns wrong result

Tags: timezone, psql

For such a query:

```
select
  s.start_time::timestamptz at time zone 'America/New_York' as t1,
  s.start_time::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC' as t2,
  s.start_time::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'America/New_York' as t3,
  s.start_time
from
  my_table s
order by
  id desc;
```

I get results like this:
[image]

As we can see, it properly returns -5 for `t1` and 0 for `t2` (my diff is +1), but result in `t3` is strange for me. What's happening there? I thought that it should be equal to `t1`, but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

`s.start_time::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'America/New_York'` means:

- take the timestamp (without time zone) and interpret it as an absolute timestamp when interpreted as being in the time zone specified by the current setting of the parameter `timezone`
- calculate what an UTC clock would show at that absolute timestamp
- take the result and calculate the absolute timestamp when a New Your wall clock would show that time

When a clock in your time zone shows `2024-03-03 22:00:00`, it is 21:00 UTC. If a New York wall clock shows `2024-03-03 21:00:00`, that is `2024-03-04 03:00:00` your local time.